# Blockfrost API 403 Error in React Node JS app

Tags: blockfrost, react, reactjs

I'm trying to get info about the latest block in my React Node JS app using Blockfrost and I'm running into an error:

```
GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/blocks/latest 403 (Forbidden)
```

Why is this happening? Any potential solutions are much appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch(
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/blocks/latest',
  {
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
      project_id: PROJECT_ID
    },
    method: 'GET'
  }
)
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`)
    }
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

}, [])

Answer (score 1):

Your URL appears to be incorrect:

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/blocks/latest
```